# CCTexture2d not showing in retina

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've been trying to add retina support to my game and it's been pretty rough. I make a CCTexture2D, and then the image is drawn to the screen at 2x the size, as it would be if it were not retina.

My code:

inside `init`:

```
wallTexture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"wallTexture.png"];
[wallTexture setResolutionType:kCCResolutioniPhone5RetinaDisplay];
[wallTexture setAliasTexParameters];
```

inside `draw`:

```
for (NSArray * wall in walls) {
    [wallTexture drawAtPoint:CGPointMake([wall[0] intValue], [wall[0] intValue])];
}
```

My normal `CCSprite`'s draw in retina just fine, but when I try to draw the `wallTexture` to the canvas, it does not show up as 1:1 px, rather it is 1:2px. Is there any reason why this could happen?

Edit:

It displays properly when I use the file as the src for a CCSprite.

Comment: You don't need to call out the -hd when refering to retinal images.  Cocos2d does that for you.

Comment: Alright, I fixed that. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: you also shouldn't set the resolution type manually when using the -hd etc suffixes